# Filling missing value in group

Tags: r, missing-data

I have data frame where some of the values are missing

```
A 1
A NA
A NA
B NA
B 2
B NA
C NA
C NA
C NA
```

How can I fill in groups where I have data?

Comment: Can you please include the expected output?

Comment: All members of A have 1, B 2 and C NA as we have no data for C

Comment: What happens if there are rows with different values for A or B?

Comment: Is it assured that A will have only one value that is 1? Can A have two values like 1 for first row and 2 for second row?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternative solution, though perhaps a bit flawed in how many assumptions it makes:

```
library(dplyr)
y %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  arrange(V2) %>%
  mutate(V2 = V2[1])
# Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
# Groups: V1 [3]
#      V1    V2
#   (chr) (int)
# 1     A     1
# 2     A     1
# 3     A     1
# 4     B     2
# 5     B     2
# 6     B     2
# 7     C    NA
# 8     C    NA
# 9     C    NA
```

Answer (score 19):

You can also use `fill` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  fill(v1) %>%
  fill(v1, .direction = "up")
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID    v1
  <chr> <int>
1     A     1
2     A     1
3     A     1
4     B     2
5     B     2
6     B     2
7     C    NA
8     C    NA
9     C    NA
```

Credits to @akrun for `dput`

Answer (score 5):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', we assign (`:=`) the column 'v1' as the first non-NA value.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, v1:= v1[!is.na(v1)][1L] , by = ID]
df1
#   ID v1
#1:  A  1
#2:  A  1
#3:  A  1
#4:  B  2
#5:  B  2
#6:  B  2
#7:  C NA
#8:  C NA
#9:  C NA
```

---

Or using only `base R`

```
 with(df1, ave(v1, ID, FUN = function(x)
          replace(x, is.na(x), x[!is.na(x)][1L])))
 #[1]  1  1  1  2  2  2 NA NA NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C"), v1 = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("ID", 
"v1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```