# Fill missing values based on available values in a group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to fill missing values not based on LOCF but based on what values are available for that group. While I was able to do this based on the answer from [Filling missing value in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962324/filling-missing-value-in-group) , I am looking for explanation about :

**Question a)** `(Final_Rank = Final_Rank[1])`. The poster didn't explain this part.

**Question b)** are there any other more efficient (in terms of speed) methods? I saw one using `Data.Table`, but I am not too familiar with it. I was unable to do this using `Data.Table`. The actual data are of size 2GB.

**Here's my data:**

```
dput(DF)
structure(list(SL3 = c("SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SW", 
"SW", "SW", "SW", "SW", "SW"), SL6 = c("SL123", "SL123", "SL123", 
"SL123", "SL123", "SL124", "SL123", "SL123", "SL123", "SL123", 
"SL123", "SL124"), Sname = c("123 Inc", "123 Inc", "123 Inc", 
"123 Inc", "123 Inc", "234 Inc", "345 Inc", "345 Inc", "345 Inc", 
"345 Inc", "345 Inc", "567 Inc"), Group = c("Red", "Sapphire", 
"Red", "Sapphire", "White", "Red", "Red", "Sapphire", "Red", 
"Sapphire", "White", "Red"), Final_Rank = c("High", "Medium", 
NA, NA, "Low", NA, "High", "Medium", NA, NA, "Low", NA), Value = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), .Names = c("SL3", "SL6", "Sname", 
"Group", "Final_Rank", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Here's my code:**

```
DF%>% 
  dplyr::group_by(SL3,SL6, Sname, Group) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(SL3,SL6, Sname, Group, Final_Rank) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Final_Rank = Final_Rank[1])
```

**Expected Output:**

```
     SL3   SL6   Sname    Group Final_Rank Value
   <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>      <chr> <dbl>
1     SE SL123 123 Inc      Red       High     1
2     SE SL123 123 Inc      Red       High     3
3     SE SL123 123 Inc Sapphire     Medium     2
4     SE SL123 123 Inc Sapphire     Medium     4
5     SE SL123 123 Inc    White        Low     5
6     SE SL124 234 Inc      Red       <NA>     6
7     SW SL123 345 Inc      Red       High     1
8     SW SL123 345 Inc      Red       High     3
9     SW SL123 345 Inc Sapphire     Medium     2
10    SW SL123 345 Inc Sapphire     Medium     4
11    SW SL123 345 Inc    White        Low     5
12    SW SL124 567 Inc      Red       <NA>     6
```

As we can see above, because no Final_Rank exists elsewhere for row#12, and row#6, I would get `NA`. Had I used `tidyr::fill()`, those would have been filled.

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me with the above two questions.

Comment: `Final_Rank = Final_Rank[1]` simply replaces `Final_Rank` with the first value of `Final_Rank`. If there is a non-NA it will be the first.

Comment: @Haboryme - Thanks for your help...Could you please explain what do you mean by "first" value--do you mean the first value in a grouped set? If so, then by doing `Final_Rank[2]`, I should get some numbers and some `NA`s, but I get all `NA`s. Not sure why.

Comment: I might me wrong, it seems more complicated than, as you pointed out Final_Rank[2] returns only NA's. I get the same issue with data.table. I'll admit I don't know why.

Comment: You get all NAs because when you order the NAs are always last (try `x <- c(1, 2, NA, 6, 11, NA, 9); x[order(x)]`). So if you have 2 values which are `c('High', NA)` then `Final_Rank[2] == NA`. On the other hand if you only have 1 value (i.e. `c('High')`) then trying to get the second element (with `Final_Rank[2]`) will result to NA (since it doesnt exist).

Comment: @Sotos I thought one of them had 2 non-NA's values, I misread. It makes sense then, ty.

Comment: Of note: `fill` from `tidyr` will give you the `NA`'s as well because they are present in a group with only one entry (which is `NA`) so there is nothing else to fill with. Also, if you had more than one valid entry in `Final_Rank` within  a group, `fill` would use the last value instead of the first to replace the `NA`s. Which do you want? It sounds like you are happy with the result from the approach you describe, but the one alternative you mention would give a different output in complicated situations. Is filling with the first value appropriate? What do you want in an answer?

Comment: @Mark Peterson - Thanks for your help. I tried using `fill`, but it did fill the rows that should have been `NA`. I tried both `.down` and `.up`. It seems you had success with `fill`, can you please help me with a solution?

Comment: I took your sample data and replaced the `mutate` line at the end with `fill(Final_Rank)` and got the `NA` entries. Note that you do still need to `group_by` to avoid `fill` going beyond your desired groups.

Comment: I'll ask again: What about the behavior of your current approach is incorrect? Is it just speed that you are looking to change, or is there something else?

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for your help. Nothing wrong with my implementation. I was interested in feedback on my approach and other methods that could save me a few seconds. I also tried your approach about `fill()`. It does work. However, the difference between `fill` and `Final_Rank[1]` is that former takes last value, while in latter we are explicitly taking the top most value to fill the `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Part A, here is @Haboryme's comment (preserved in an answer):

> `Final_Rank = Final_Rank[1]` simply replaces `Final_Rank` with the first value of `Final_Rank`. If there is a non-NA it will be the first. – Haboryme

To expand just a bit, when using `group_by`, it will select the first entry of `Final_Rank` *within the group*. It is only first because you are `arrange`'ing by `Final_Rank` in your code. You could replace `Final_Rank[1]` with any chosen value, including constants (e.g. `"Missing"`) or a calculated value (e.g., `paste(Final_Rank %>% unique %>% sort, sep ="; ")` to concatenate all values in that group).

Just looking at the time, the `mutate` approach described is already pretty good. `data.table` solutions tend to be a little faster, but I find the syntax difficult enough that time I shave off at run-time is lost in coding/debugging (and then some) unless I am running the code a *lot*.

Here is a quick benchmark (using the `microbenchmark` package) of the current `mutate` solution, the `fill` solution suggested, and a solution generating a "look up table" with the desired entry, then joining it back in. Note that `fill` will give a different answer than the others if there is ever more than one valid `Final_Rank` entry.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  mutate =
    DF%>% 
    group_by(SL3,SL6, Sname, Group) %>%
    arrange(SL3,SL6, Sname, Group, Final_Rank) %>%
    mutate(Final_Rank = ifelse(is.na(Final_Rank), Final_Rank[1], Final_Rank))
  , fill =
    DF%>% 
    group_by(SL3,SL6, Sname, Group) %>%
    arrange(SL3,SL6, Sname, Group, Final_Rank) %>%
    fill(Final_Rank)
  , left_join =
    DF%>% 
    select(-Value) %>%
    group_by(SL3,SL6, Sname, Group) %>%
    arrange(Final_Rank) %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    rename(newRank = Final_Rank) %>%
    left_join(DF, .) %>%
    arrange(SL3,SL6, Sname, Group)

)
```

gives

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    mutate 1.783668 1.848683 1.954992 1.904577 1.968923 3.093098   100
      fill 3.299220 3.399997 3.558219 3.491215 3.573784 4.756986   100
 left_join 3.097166 3.214982 3.379452 3.300272 3.420206 4.653970   100
```

Note that the mutate solution is a fair bit faster than the other two, though other solutions may exist (and these may scale differently if the group sizes grow).

Finally, note that the current implementation replaces **ALL** entries in `Final_Rank` with the first entry in the group. If you want to only replace *missing* entries, you would need to use `ifelse` (or `fill`, as above), like so:

```
DF%>% 
  group_by(SL3,SL6, Sname, Group) %>%
  arrange(SL3,SL6, Sname, Group, Final_Rank) %>%
  mutate(Final_Rank = ifelse(is.na(Final_Rank), Final_Rank[1], Final_Rank))
```

I added that to the `microbenchmark` and it doesn't appear to be a major slow down:

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    mutate 1.752267 1.835038 1.937181 1.900086 1.946848 3.197292   100
      fill 3.289838 3.414916 3.626607 3.507186 3.618336 5.857506   100
 left_join 3.052692 3.209808 3.371702 3.260593 3.377899 6.924646   100
    ifelse 1.771460 1.813426 1.935845 1.883497 1.951977 3.113328   100
```