# Based on patient data from one row, subset that patient's other rows

Tags: r

I have 1000 patients who have come to my clinic for three visits (visit1, visit2, visit3). In the data frame, each visit is registered as a new row so I have 3000 rows. When the data was created only new information was entered for each row so that gender information only exists in the visit1-row for each patient and since we're screening for cancer at visit3 only that row can have a Yes or No for that column, the column is empty for visit2 and visit1.

What I want to do is analyze the characteristics of the patients who received a cancer diagnosis at visit3 but all the characteristics are in visit1.

I've done this:

```
cancerdiagnosed <- subset(alldata, cancerdiagnosis =='Yes')
```

But now I only have the rows at which the patients were diagnosed with cancer which lacks gender data and so on. I want to take those patientnumbers that I've gotten and use those to instead make a subset of those patients first visit.

Comment: Please can you use ``dput(head(data))`` and add the output to the main post - it will help people give a better answer. You can censor the data if it contains private data. Thank you.

Comment: This is not an uncommon problem. But it might help if you were to provide a sample of what you data looks like (try editing your question with the result of `dput(head(alldata))`). Furthermore, please provide what your "subset" (`cancerdiagnosed`) should look like. Should it have a  single row per patient, with all data included? For now, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962324/filling-missing-value-in-group) that shows how you can fill in missing values within a group (or in your case, fill gender information within a single patient).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example dataset based on your description.

```
alldata <- data.frame(patientid = 1:5, 
                      visit = rep(1:3, each = 5))
alldata$gender <- ifelse(alldata$visit == 1, c("m", "f", "m", "f", "m"), NA)
alldata$cancerdiagnosis <- ifelse(alldata$visit == 3, c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), NA)
```

With base R you can try this:

```
# looking for patientids with cancer
patients <- alldata$patientid[which(alldata$cancerdiagnosis == "Yes")]

# filtering patientids with cancer and the first visit
alldata4 <- subset(alldata, patientid %in% patients & visit == 1)



  patientid visit gender cancerdiagnosis
1         1     1      m            <NA>
3         3     1      m            <NA>
5         5     1      m            <NA>
```

An tidy approach may look like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

# looking for patientids with cancer
patients <- alldata %>% 
  filter(cancerdiagnosis == "Yes") %>% 
  pull(patientid)

# filtering for patientids with cancer and the first visit
alldata3 <- alldata %>% 
  filter(patientid %in% patients, visit == 1)
```

Alternativly you can add the information of the first visit into the following visits. In the end you get your desired information by subseting the third visit.

```
library(tidyverse)

alldata2 <- alldata %>% 
  group_by(patientid) %>%
  fill(gender) %>%
  filter(cancerdiagnosis == "Yes")


  patientid visit gender cancerdiagnosis
      <int> <int> <chr>  <chr>          
1         1     3 m      Yes            
2         3     3 m      Yes            
3         5     3 m      Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a join. First, I make a table with the additional information, then I add this to the rest of the original data with `left_join`:

```r
test_data <- data.frame(
  patient_id = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
  visit = rep(1:3, 2),
  gender = c("male", NA, NA, "female", NA, NA),
  cancerdiagnosis = c(NA, NA, "Yes", NA, NA, "No")
)

test_data
#>   patient_id visit gender cancerdiagnosis
#> 1          A     1   male            <NA>
#> 2          A     2   <NA>            <NA>
#> 3          A     3   <NA>             Yes
#> 4          B     1 female            <NA>
#> 5          B     2   <NA>            <NA>
#> 6          B     3   <NA>              No

library(dplyr)

# make a table with the general information
patient_information <- test_data %>% 
  filter(visit == 1) %>% 
  select(patient_id, gender)

patient_information
#>   patient_id gender
#> 1          A   male
#> 2          B female

# join this with the complete table
data_complete <- test_data %>% 
  select(-gender) %>% 
  left_join(patient_information, by = "patient_id")

data_complete
#>   patient_id visit cancerdiagnosis gender
#> 1          A     1            <NA>   male
#> 2          A     2            <NA>   male
#> 3          A     3             Yes   male
#> 4          B     1            <NA> female
#> 5          B     2            <NA> female
#> 6          B     3              No female
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>