# Filling missing values for multiple columns by group

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm guessing this has already been asked on here but I'm having difficulty finding this precise issue. I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
A 1 X  9  P
A 2 NA NA NA
A 3 NA NA NA
B 1 NA NA NA
B 2 Y  8  Q
B 3 NA NA NA
C 1 NA NA NA
C 2 NA NA NA
C 3 Z  7  R
```

In other words, there are groups (A, B, C) that have columns with many missing values. I want to fill those missing values using the existing values in those groups. There's always at least one row in each group that has the values that need to be filled in. The desired output would look like the following:

```
A 1 X  9  P
A 2 X  9  P
A 3 X  9  P
B 1 Y  8  Q
B 2 Y  8  Q
B 3 Y  8  Q
C 1 Z  7  R
C 2 Z  7  R
C 3 Z  7  R
```

It's very similar to this person's question ([Filling missing value in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962324/filling-missing-value-in-group)) except that I want to fill missing values in many columns rather than just one. In the example here, I've included three columns in which missing values need to be filled, but the actual data frame has many more.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you identify the columns with missing values? Or do you want to fill in missing values in every column?

Comment: Have a look at this : https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html . It gives almost the same example data with yours.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. You should provide code to your data.frame by pasting `dput(dataframe)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fill` in multiple columns and in both the directions (up and down) by group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>%
  fill(V3:V5, .direction = 'updown') %>%
  ungroup()

#  V1       V2 V3       V4 V5   
#  <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <chr>
#1 A         1 X         9 P    
#2 A         2 X         9 P    
#3 A         3 X         9 P    
#4 B         1 Y         8 Q    
#5 B         2 Y         8 Q    
#6 B         3 Y         8 Q    
#7 C         1 Z         7 R    
#8 C         2 Z         7 R    
#9 C         3 Z         7 R
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C"), V2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), V3 = c("X", 
NA, NA, NA, "Y", NA, NA, NA, "Z"), V4 = c(9L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 
NA, NA, NA, 7L), V5 = c("P", NA, NA, NA, "Q", NA, NA, NA, "R")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The zoo package has a `na.locf` function and it has a data.frame method so just sort the data first on ever column except V2 (since NA will drop to the bottom) and then fill in:

```
> dat <- read.table(text=txt)
> dat <- dat[order(dat$V1, dat$V3, dat$V4,dat$V5), ]
> dat2 <- na.locf(dat)
> dat2
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  A  1  X  9  P
2  A  2  X  9  P
3  A  3  X  9  P
5  B  2  Y  8  Q
4  B  1  Y  8  Q
6  B  3  Y  8  Q
9  C  3  Z  7  R
7  C  1  Z  7  R
8  C  2  Z  7  R
```

If there are groups with all NA's in one or more columns, then you  need to first do a `split` or `group_by` operation. Otherwise there will be  carry over from a prior group.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following solution. I used `coalesce` function, assuming that there is only one value to be used to replace `NA`s. If there are more than one value to be used in each group per value I need to modify this solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(across(V2:V5, ~ coalesce(.x, .x[!is.na(.x)])))

# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   V1 [3]
  V1       V2 V3       V4 V5   
  <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <chr>
1 A         1 X         9 P    
2 A         2 X         9 P    
3 A         3 X         9 P    
4 B         1 Y         8 Q    
5 B         2 Y         8 Q    
6 B         3 Y         8 Q    
7 C         1 Z         7 R    
8 C         2 Z         7 R    
9 C         3 Z         7 R
```